# How can I send 2 different PHP arrays to JavaScript?

Tags: php, json, ajax

How can I send 2 arrays to JavaScript and use them in another part of the JavaScript file? (sorry I'm a newbie and struggling all evening with this question)

I have a php file with 2 arrays. In the JavaScript I have an ajax request to get the arrays. But I can return only one. And I cannot save the output so I can `for each` it later.

```
//Get arrays

 $.ajax(
 {
   type: 'get',
   url: '../classes/bestanden_overzicht_client.php',
   data: "id="+id,
     success:function(data)//we got the response of ajax :)
     {
    <-- how can i target the 2 arrays and send them to function below --> 
     },
     error:function(data)
     {
     //no respons show error.
     alert  ("error!");
     alert(JSON.stringify(data)) //we give an alert of the error when there is no respons from ajax
     ;}
});

("#images").fileinput({
        uploadAsync: false,
        overwriteInitial: false,
initialPreview: [

<-- want here the output of the array1


],
intialConfig [

<-- Want here the output of array2

]



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();

$array1[0] = "numbers"; 
$array1[1] = "letters"; 

$array2[0] = "forname"; 
$array2[0] = "surname"; 

echo json_encode($array1);
echo json_encode($array2);
?>
```

Comment: put it in one "big master" array, _then_ encode it. `$return = ["array1"=>$array1, "array2"=>$array2];` then `echo json_encode($return);`

Comment: then you'll have it in javascript there: `var array1 = data.array1;`

Comment: thnx and how can i use the output outside the ajax request?

Comment: __BUT__ you need to get rid of the `<script...>` in your php file! this way javascript gets confused.... "unexpected character"

Comment: hm... you then would need to set a global js var to data.array1 and ...2. define that var outside the ajax: `var myData;`, in success-function do `myData = data;`. Then (and only __after__ the successful ajax call) you can use it in your function: `initialPreview: myData.array1,`

Comment: You have to put all the code that uses the response into the `success:` function. You can't use it in other parts because AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: Ok thanks all for the quick response.  You helped me a lot.

Comment: I'll write my first comment as an answer then. Might be helpful for future visitors. You are free the accept it...

Answer (score 3):

You can only send *one* json encoded object to javascript. To solve that, put your two arrays into one array, then encode that and send it back:

```
$return = ["array1"=>$array1, "array2"=>$array2]; 
echo json_encode($return);
```

you'll be able to access it in your ajax call there:

```
//..
success: function(data) {
    var array1 = data.array1;
},
//...
```